# Google Earth Model in Blender to Twinmotion

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a google earth model in Blender with textures from the cityscape that I need to bring into Twinmotion. However, when I import the .fbx file into Twinmotion, the textures/materials import but have no image associated with it. I'm not sure if this has to do with the export settings out of Blender or if this is a Twinmotion issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Never heard of TwinMotion, but maybe this: [fbx export why there are no materials or textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) applies here?